# Test case for firebase setup & SNS notification in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, push-notification, amazon-sns

I am looking to write a test case for firebase setup but couldn't find any resources can someone please help me with that?

I tried the firebase authentication test case for push notifications but it didn't work